# DataStax Java Driver: get row after insert fails

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I'm facing issues when trying to insert an item to Cassandra table. Here is my situation(I'm using the DataStax Java Driver):

1. I have a table for each row it has a TTL of 60000 seconds.
2. I insert an entry in the table and it was successfully applied(`wasApplied()==true`).
3. When I try to get that entry later, the entry is not found. I'm sure it is within the TTL period.
4. When I test the same scenario locally on my machine, everything is working fine. But when I deploy the code to the server, it has the wired behavior described here.

What could be the possible problem?

Comment: Which driver version are you using ? and How many app server do you have ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Q1: I am using version 3.1.1. Q2: I'm not sure.

Comment: Q2. I mean using datastax driver from how many server you are accessing cassandra ?

Comment: Only one server I guess. BTW, I also have other Cassandra tables but this is the only table with this problem.

Comment: Show the `desc your_table_name` output

Comment: I don't have access to the database now, will give you the result once I get access to it.

Comment: Just make sure that the table don't have default ttl with lower value than your expected

Comment: And also make sure all the server's clock is synchronized

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!